# Rendimiento de base de datos MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, windows, docker

Buenas noches tengo una consulta, estoy creando un sistema de gestión de ventas en c# para 3 sucursales con múltiples usuarios y todos se conectarán al mismo tiempo y a un mismo servidor, mi consulta es creen que se sature mucho el flujo de datos ? o eso depende netamente de la capacidad del servidor?, que sistema operativo me conviene instalar windows o linux?, estuve viendo el asunto de doker creen que en alguno de esos 3 casos pueda tener un flujo de trabajo mas rápido?

De antemano agradezco cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usarás un SGBD como PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, etc.... Lo mejor será que uses Linux, de hecho, la mayoría de los servidores usan Linux.

Por otro lado si usas un SGBD como SQLServer que corre bajo Windows, no tienes por donde elegir.

La velocidad de respuesta de la base de datos dependerá del hardware que tengas asignado para ello. Con Linux explotas todos los recursos de la PC y puedes darle al SGBD bastante recursos. No se que tan usado sea el sistema pero por lo que dices no creo que supere los 500 usuarios concurrentes.

Considera picos de actividad, por ejemplo, navidad, año nuevo, vacaciones, que se yo, algún momento donde explote la actividad de los usuarios del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que crees un escenario donde realizar pruebas de carga, todo sistema tiene un limite especifico con un hardware concreto , es importante saber este limite para escalar la solucion cuando sea preciso.

Mas [informacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/vsts/load-test/run-performance-tests-app-before-release)